# Windows 7 bridge

Tags: windows-7, networking

My setup

Router <-> PC <-> NAS (All ethernet cables)

I have 4 eth ports on my PC. One goes to router and the other goes to NAS. They are two separate network. Now I want to share the NAS across the network. I want the NAS discoverable by the router. I don't want to run a cable from my NAS to router because it is too far.

Is it possible with Windows 7 bridge? It seems when I bridge the network cards, they just both get 1 IP address which is what I don't want.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. When you say "they just both get 1 IP address", both what? What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to get a cheap switch. Connect the cable that currently goes to your PC to the switch. Connect the NAS to the switch with a cable. Five port gigagit switches are [available](http://www.walmart.com/ip/TP-Link-TL-SG1005D-5-Port-Unmanaged-Gigabit-Desktop-Switch/17133240) for $20 or so.